# XMLHTTP request: too many requests even when under throttle limit

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

The project is a school homework where we make API requests to fetch some cryptocurrency dummy data and show the results on a diagram.
The diagram drawing is done using Chart.js, that works fine on any data I resent. The problem is with fetching the data.

I have the following simple code that does the request periodically:

```
setInterval(function fetchData() {
    console.log("BTC fetched");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://obudai-api.azurewebsites.net/api/exchange    /btc", true);

    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Access-Token", secretKey);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            bitcoin = res["currentRate"];
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();

}, 15000);
```

I have 3 of this function called, each for a different cryptocurrency.

I looked up a Chrome diagnostics and the results are

[image: error1]

[image: error 2]

[image: error 3]

**Note: the throttle limit is 10 calls / 15 seconds. With my setup I make 3 calls / 15 seconds, or, when in debug mode 6 calls/15 seconds.** It definitely should work as it works for others but I'm unsure why it does that.

Update: after the help from the comments, I can finally show the response message. It looks like so:

[image]

I'm fetching the current date.

Updating the code, now using timeout and recursion:

```
let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://obudai-api.azurewebsites.net/api/exchange/btc", true);

    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Access-Token", secretKey);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            bitcoin = res["currentRate"];
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();

    timerId = setTimeout(tick, 5000); // (*)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Looks like a [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. I also think you should put a `debugger` before setting the interval and check how many times it's been called (look in the stack to see what's calling it).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I asked the tutor about it (I tried this using Firefox as well which stated CORS issue, just as you said) and they told us they turned off those settings, so we have an easier time implementing this.

Comment: I know there is a chrome plugin that [allows cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) even if the API provider does not (it circumvent the browser restriction). I still think you are setting the interval too many times and would advice to put a `debugger` statement there to see how many times you set the interval and from where.

Comment: Plugin added and I set a debugger (as well as a console.log just to be sure) and it gets executed on every 5 seconds. Now I don't get the errors, but I get the same value as output, just like before :/

Comment: I suggest you use timeout and call recursive.

Comment: I think there are some security reason(flood attack) will reject you when you call a lot of times

Comment: I updated the question with finally the response text. I check out that timeout and recursive stuff.

Comment: Error is `cannot read property add of undefined` nowhere in the code you posted do I see `.add` so the error is caused by code not posted in your question.

Comment: I updated the question again, now with the timeout code. It does all the same.

Comment: The error was added while I was waiting for some replies. I go ahead and remove it, thank you for pointing it out. It didn't influence the behaviour though.